# Python 3: Error en juego de adivinar el número con randint

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

para probar el modulo random estuve probando hacer un juego muy simple de adivinar un número. El problema es que no funciona cómo debería y ni siquiera sé exactamente bajo que situaciones falla.
El juego debería decir "un poco más bajo" cuando el número que escojes es mayor al número otorgado por el randint, "un poco más alto" cuando el número es menor y luego llamar a la función adivina_el_número recursivamente para darle al jugador otra oportunidad. El problema es que a veces no imprime lo que debe imprimir y a veces no imprime nada. Les dejo el código para que lo ejecuten y lo vean por ustedes mismos:

```
import random
random = random.randint(1,10)
print(random)
def adivina():
    adivina = input("ingrese un número del uno al 10: ")
    return adivina
def adivina_el_número():
    try:
        if random == int(adivina()):
            print("!Adivinaste el número¡")
            return 
        elif random < int(adivina()):
            print("Un poco más alto.")
            adivina_el_número()
            return
        elif random > int(adivina()):
            print("un poco más bajo")
            adivina_el_número()
            return
    except:
        print("Por favor ingrese un número válido del una al diez")
        adivina_el_número()

adivina_el_número()
```

Nota: imprimi el valor de random para ayudarme a testear el código durante la depuración

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas, veamos:

- En primer lugar las comparaciones están justamente al revés, si `random < int(adivina())` el número elegido es mayor, por lo que el mensaje debiera ser `"un poco más bajo"`.
- El otro problema es que estás volviendo a pedir un número en cada `elif`, eso no tiene sentido, deberías pedir un número al principio y verificar el mismo con las tres condiciones posibles igual, mayor o menor.

Quedaría más o menos así:

```
import random
random = random.randint(1,10)
print(random)

def adivina():
    adivina = input("ingrese un número del uno al 10: ")
    return adivina

def adivina_el_número():
    try:
        numero = int(adivina())
        if random == numero:
            print("!Adivinaste el número¡")
            return 
        elif random > numero:
            print("Un poco más alto.")
            adivina_el_número()
            return
        elif random < numero:
            print("un poco más bajo")
            adivina_el_número()
            return
    except:
        print("Por favor ingrese un número válido del una al diez")
        adivina_el_número()

adivina_el_número()
```

- El otro tema que podría ser un problema, es que usas un algoritmo recursivo, es decir por cada interacción con el usuario vuelves a llamar a la misma función, en Python y en otros lenguajes, hay límites en la cantidad de recursiones, si mal no recuerdo en python son 1000. Obviamente para adivinar un número del 1 al 10, hacen falta como máximo 10 intentos, por lo que el problema de la recursividad no parecería tal, sin embargo te sugiero usar otra estructura como la de `while`de esta forma:

.

```
import random

def adivina():
    num = input("ingrese un número del uno al 10: ")
    return num

random = random.randint(1,10)
print(random)

numero = 0
while numero != random:
  numero = int(adivina())
  if random == numero:
      print("!Adivinaste el número¡")
      break
  elif random > numero:
      print("Un poco más alto.")
  elif random < numero:
      print("un poco más bajo")
```